# Angular open new window and display xml

Tags: angular, xml, angular7

I would like to open a new window after a click event and show an xml structure. I do not want that browser interpret my xml.

I tried with this:

```
window.open('data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><RootTag>'+xml+'</RootTag>', "", "_blank")
```

with chrome this do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with this code in the component.ts

```
    let blob = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/xml'});
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

This open a new window with the view just for xml.

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions here

1. To open a window either use a popup / modal control (for example [NgBootstrap Modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)) or use angular routing to navigate to a different page.
2. To just show xml write it in interpolation. Something like this.

```html
<div style="white-space:pre; font-size:12px; font-family:monospace;">{{getXML()}}</div>
```

and in the component,

```js
  getXML() {
    return "<RootTag>xml</RootTag>";
  }
```

Please find [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-trarri?file=src/app/app.component.ts).